# why does this R line graph split towards the end?

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting a line graph in R on the following data:

```
>bwlist
$bw1
[1] 2321

$bw2
[1] 2443

$bw3
[1] 2572

$bw4
[1] 2707

$bw5
[1] 2850

$bw6
[1] 3000

$bw7
[1] 3150

$bw8
[1] 3307

$bw9
[1] 3646

$bw10
[1] 3000

$bw11
[1] 3828


>meanp

$bw1
[1] -0.0905383

$bw2
[1] -0.0902568

$bw3
[1] -0.09018387

$bw4
[1] -0.09032931

$bw5
[1] -0.09061729

$bw6
[1] -0.09096098

$bw7
[1] -0.09131482

$bw8
[1] -0.091703

$bw9
[1] -0.0925732

$bw10
[1] -0.09096098

$bw11
[1] -0.09298849
```

Using the function:

```
plot(bwlist, meanp, type="l", xlab="Bandwidth", ylab="Mean", main="Fixed Gaussian")
```

The graph that comes out looks like:

[image]

If you look closely at the end of the line in the right bottom corner you can clearly see that this splits towards the end. Why?

EDIT:

to ease data view:

```
structure(list(bw1 = 2321, bw2 = 2443, bw3 = 2572, bw4 = 2707, 
bw5 = 2850, bw6 = 3000, bw7 = 3150, bw8 = 3307, bw9 = 3646, 
bw10 = 3000, bw11 = 3828), .Names = c("bw1", "bw2", "bw3", 


structure(list(bw1 = -0.0905382962184256, bw2 = -0.0902568016836197, 
bw3 = -0.0901838736559796, bw4 = -0.0903293110305972, bw5 = -0.0906172878539612, 
bw6 = -0.0909609806783894, bw7 = -0.0913148229896919, bw8 = -0.0917029957618266, 
bw9 = -0.0925732030022296, bw10 = -0.0909609806783894, bw11 = -0.092988492295963), .Names = c("bw1", 
"bw2", "bw3", "bw4", "bw5", "bw6", "bw7", "bw8", "bw9", "bw10", 
"bw11"))
```

Comment: because bw10 and bw6 are both 3000

Comment: can you please post your data via `dput(bwlist)` and `dput(meanp)`

Comment: @Floo0 the data is there.

Comment: @nongkrong I see that the value 3000 repeats but shouldn't the graph make a bend instead of split?

Comment: @johnred it connects the dots in order, so you get a backtrack, then the second line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the split line because bw10 and bw6 are both 3000.  A simple fix would be

```
plot(bwlist[-10], meanp[-10], type="l", xlab="Bandwidth", ylab="Mean", main="Fixed Gaussian")
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you want to plot the sorted values:

```
bwlist <- unlist(bwlist)
meanp <- unlist(meanp)

meanp <- meanp[order(bwlist)]
bwlist <- sort(bwlist)

plot(bwlist, meanp, type="l", xlab="Bandwidth", ylab="Mean", main="Fixed Gaussian")
```

[image: resulting plot]